# Subfigures (if) on different pages with main captions on each page

Tags: pdftex, subfloats

I would like to make multiple subfigures and if there is a pagebreak in between than I want that the main caption appears on every page (If I reference with \ref{} it should just go to the first one). Something like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{float}%
\usepackage{scrhack}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}%
\usepackage[list=true,hypcap=true]{subcaption}%
\usepackage{hyperref}%

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-3]% CHANGE 3 to 4 for pagebreak between figure a and b    
    \begin{figure}[H]%
        \hfill%
        \subcaptionbox{Dummy 1.\label{subfig:Dummy1}}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
        \hspace*{\fill}%
        
        % I want this caption ONLY if pictures A and B are on the same, else only the caption below should be printed. (Ofc the label should than also be below)
        \caption{Main caption.}%
        \label{fig:Dummy}%
    \end{figure}%
    \begin{figure}[H]\ContinuedFloat%
        \hfill%
        \subcaptionbox{Dummy 2.\label{subfig:Dummy2}}{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
        \hspace*{\fill}%
        \caption{Main caption.}%
    \end{figure}%

    % Test references
    \lipsum[1]
    Figure (a): \ref{subfig:Dummy1}\\
    Figure (b): \ref{subfig:Dummy2}\\
    Figure (1): \ref{fig:Dummy}\\
    \lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Ofc this is not a working example ^^, since it results in

[image]

if both of the figures are on the same page. I would like to have only one main caption (bottom) if the subfigures aren't on different pages. Any suggestions? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figures are formatted immediately, so the only way to get the page number is via the aux file (`\getpagerefnumber`). It is provided by hyperref, but see refcount for documentation.

Note: It takes two runs to reflect a change in the page numbers.

The easiest solution to moving the anchor is to use `\hyperlink{...}{\ref*{...}}` instead of `\ref`.  An alternative would be to change `\@currentHref` between `\caption` and `\label`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{float}%
\usepackage{scrhack}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}%
\usepackage[list=true,hypcap=true]{subcaption}%
\usepackage{hyperref}%

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-4]% CHANGE 3 to 4 for pagebreak between figure a and b  
    \begin{figure}[H]%
        \hypertarget{fig:Dummy}%
        \hfill%
        \subcaptionbox{Dummy 1.\label{subfig:Dummy1}}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
        \hspace*{\fill}%
        \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{subfig:Dummy2}>\getpagerefnumber{subfig:Dummy1}\relax
          \caption{Main caption.}%
        \fi
    \end{figure}%
    \begin{figure}[H]\ContinuedFloat%
        \hfill%
        \subcaptionbox{Dummy 2.\label{subfig:Dummy2}}{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
        \hspace*{\fill}%
        \caption{Main caption.}%
        \label{fig:Dummy}%
    \end{figure}%

    % Test references
    \lipsum[1]
    Figure (a): \ref{subfig:Dummy1}\\
    Figure (b): \ref{subfig:Dummy2}\\
    Figure (1): \hyperlink{fig:Dummy}{\ref*{fig:Dummy}}\\
    \lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem with the caption. <3 Now I only want ofc that if I use `\ref{fig:Dummy}` that it jumps to the top in both cases. Any suggestions? :D

Comment: Yes I know that one can only define one label, but the problem now is that if you click on the reference created by '\ref{fig:Dummy}' in the pdf when both pictures are on the same page, that it doesn't jump to the top, rather only to figure B. :/ @John

Comment: Does it work for you? Because if I click at [1] in the pdf it doesn't jump to the top to displays both A and B for me as it should for a caption. :D @John

Comment: Hm yeah thought it wouldn't work to make a label in another figure/place than the caption... Thanks. :D
(I just thought if there would be a solution it would be practical since if I write above some paragraphs more in my thesis it automatically gets adjusted)

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution (@John) that works now with pagebreaks and always references to the top picture for `\ref{fig:Dummy}` independent if the pictures are on the same side or not. :D I don't know if the spaces below and at the top are now exactly the same as with the figure environment (if somebody knows, would be delighted), but at least it works and looks exaclty the same.
Btw. it needs the package `\usepackage[breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}` which I always load anyway.

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[%
    breakable,%
    arc=0mm, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,%
    left=0pt, right = 0pt, top=0pt, bottom=1mm, boxsep=0pt,%
    enhanced standard jigsaw,%
    after skip=1\baselineskip,%
    before skip=1\baselineskip,%
    opacityback=0,%
    ]%
    {\captionsetup{type=figure}%
        \hfill%
        \subcaptionbox{Dummy 1.\label{subfig:Dummy1}}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
        \hspace*{\fill}%
        \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{subfig:Dummy1}<\getpagerefnumber{subfig:Dummy2}\relax
            \caption{Main caption.}%
            \ContinuedFloat%
        \fi%
        \par%
        \hfill%
        \subcaptionbox{Dummy 2.\label{subfig:Dummy2}}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
        \hspace*{\fill}%
        \caption{Main caption.}%
        \label{fig:Dummy}%
    }%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
```